# Ansible | VPC | Ec2 | Dynamic Inventory file creation error |

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a VPC and deploy two ec2 instances from a local host. There was an error while creating the inventory file the public IP is not fetching from the loop.

Here is the code :

```
  ######################Launching Web Server#######################
    - name: "Launching Web Server"
      ec2:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        region: "{{ region }}"
        key_name: "{{ keypair_name }}"
        instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ image_id }}"
        group: Webserver-sg
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ web_subnet.subnet.id }}"
        instance_tags:
          Name: "webserver"
        count_tag:
          Name: "webserver"
        exact_count: 1
        wait: true

 
    - name: "Fetching Ec2 Instance Details"
      ec2_instance_info:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        region: "{{ region }}"
        filters:
          vpc-id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
          instance-state-name: [ "running"]
      register: ec2
            
  ###########Creating Dynamic Inventory for webserver###############

    - name: "Creating Dynamic Inventory"
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        groups: "local_webserver"
        ansible_host: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        ansible_port: 22
        ansible_user: "ec2-user"
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ keypair_name }}.pem"
        ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

And here are the error when creating the Dynamic Inventory file.

```
TASK [Creating Dynamic Inventory] ********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'public_ip'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/new_vpc/main.yml': line 215, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  ###########Creating Dynamic Inventory for webserver###############\n    - name: \"Creating Dynamic Inventory\"\n      ^ here\n"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT ***********************************************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Hi Jebin C Varghese welcome to SO. In the future, you'll get faster results by using `- debug: var=item` or `- debug: var=ec2.instances` to troubleshoot your own setup, as questions like this are almost always at risk of closure for being a typo since they don't help anyone else unless they happen to make that same mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As their page says, [use of `ec2:` is not recommended](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html#synopsis) and that's likely why it does not document the return values the same way that `ec2_instance:` does, otherwise one could have seen that the attribute is [`public_ip_address`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/aws/ec2_instance_module.html#return-instances/public_ip_address)

Comment: It's worked. I have changed the register value to ec2_status and the loop worked.